# Iterate the list items that were prompted as a result of entering a search string in a input box and read and select

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to automate a two step process. First I enter some two character search string into an input box, when it prompts the probable search results as a list, I need to read each item and look for  a specific text and click the one I wanted to be taken as the search item in the original input box.

When I used the Firebug inside the Firefox, I see this code being highlighted. Of course, it is only two items here but can be a lot more up to 10.

```html
<div class="ac_results" style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 400px; top: 135px; left: 520px;">
<ul>
<li class="ac_even ac_over">
EURIBOR 3 MONTH FUT (
<strong>EB</strong>
)
</li>
<li class="ac_odd">
EUR/GBP FUTURES (
<strong>EB</strong>
P)
</li>
</ul>
```

I need to be able to iterate the prompted list, select one, and click it.
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.className("ac_results"));

public List<WebElement> getDropDownOptions() {
    if (dropDownOptions == null) {
        dropDownOptions = dropdown.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
    }
    return new ArrayList<>(dropDownOptions);
}
```

You should be able to iterate over the returned list.

Comment: I am unable to understand this solution, but looks very promising. How come Java code using Selenium API can access style sheet objects like @FindBy(className = "ac_results") ?

Comment: @FindBy is a part of Serenity BDD library, so in pure Selenium it will read differently. See edited answer.